# Problem with KML in Google Earth iOS-App

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz, iphone, ipad

I have a some what strange problem with KML/KMZ-files in the iOS google earth-app for ipad/iphone. I export my map from ArcMap to KMZ. Email myself and open the file with KMZ-loader and then open the file in Google Earth.

The problem is that google earth does not draw the points in the file. It works fine with lines and polygons and I can't understand what's the problem.

If I touch the "bookmarks" next to the search bar, I can see all the points and read the attributes for every point. I can even zoom to each one but nothing shows on the map.

Any one have a possible solution to this?

Regards/ Olof

Comment: I need to look closer at what you are saying. My experience is that any kmz would not open in GE_IOS.I will have to try it with my line service. Are your points being rendered as simple symbology?

Comment: It's works with the app KMZ-loader. The problem is that the graphics for points doesn't show on the map, but they are clearly in the program.

Comment: is the kmz loader new? maybe today I can see what you're talking about.

Comment: I think it's the kmz-loader that is causing the trouble. We tried another app for android platform and it worked. But the android app seems unstaible too.

Answer (score 1):

Google earth has been updated to open kml and kmz